# How can I hide the modal programatically in vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to create a component in vue js 2. It is a modal component. The function of this is to just alert a user for successful query on the database or errors. So when the user submitted a form successful or not this modal component will be shown. I did successfully shown it but the problem is I want to automatically hide it in few seconds after it is shown. How can I achieve this in vue JS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) javascript function.

```
showModal(){
   var self = this;
   self.modalActive = true;
   setTimeout(function(){
      self.modalActive = false; // Use your variable name
   }, 5 * 1000); // Hide after 5 secs
}
```

Comment: I tried this one but its not working on me? Did that work on your machine?